# Twitter API Oauth2 issue getting Access Token

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

Following this guide: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token. I am getting this error when making the POST oauth2/token at the step 3 request:

`

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 99,
            "message": "Unable to verify your credentials",
            "label": "authenticity_token_error"
        }
    ]
}
```

`

This is my request: (Note that I hide the client_id and code). The code is the one I receive after the step 2, doing the GET oauth2/authorize callback. Header: Content-Type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

[My Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUQGO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the problem was that in the Bot Application, editing the Auth settings of my twitter app, I had the option: Confidential client which needed a Basic Auth = authorization: Basic ${'username + password encoded here'}